# How can i connect 3 class to each other with using annotations?(JPA/Spring-Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, data-annotations, persistence.xml

I'm working on Spring Boot project. I have class as you see below. When i run project it give me error like that "Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution". I know that my problem depent to "annotation". How can reach good solution which have got true annotation?

for Tweet table:
'''

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tweet")
public class Tweet {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String tweetID;
    private String parentTweetID;
    private String avatar;
    private String owner_name;
    private String owner_nick;
    private String content;
    private String sent_time;
    private String sent_date;
    private String retweet_count;
    private String like_count;
    private String owner_link;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "thread_id")
    private Thread thread;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "tweet")
    private List<Media> mediaURLs;

     ....(getter/setter)
    }
```

for Thread Table:

```
@Entity
public class Thread {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "thread")
    private List<Tweet> listOfTweets;

       .....(getter/setter)

       }
```

for Media table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="media")
public class Media {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String mediaID;
    private String mediaType;
    private String mediaUrl;
    private String mediaUrlHttps;
    private String mediaVideoUrl;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tweetID")
    private Tweet tweet;

    .....(getter/setter)


    }
```

Actually i expect result like that. 
https://prnt.sc/mj7nxq

application.properties file:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tweetdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    spring.datasource.username=tweet
    spring.datasource.password=root
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    spring.thymeleaf.templates_root=src/main/resources/templates/
    logging.level.org.springframework.web= DEBUG
    logging.level.com.savetweet= DEBUG
    logging.level.org.hibernate= ERROR
```

Output:

```
    2019-02-10 21:09:03.662  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] com.savetweet.tweet.TweetApplication     : Starting TweetApplication on DESKTOP-ND86E11 with PID 7080 (C:\Users\iko\Desktop\tweet\target\classes started by iko in C:\Users\iko\Desktop\tweet)
    2019-02-10 21:09:03.668 DEBUG 7080 --- [  restartedMain] com.savetweet.tweet.TweetApplication     : Running with Spring Boot v2.1.2.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.4.RELEASE
    2019-02-10 21:09:03.669  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] com.savetweet.tweet.TweetApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/C:/Users/iko/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.5/groovy-2.5.5.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    2019-02-10 21:09:04.037  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
    2019-02-10 21:09:04.037  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
    2019-02-10 21:09:05.035  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2019-02-10 21:09:05.125  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 79ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
    2019-02-10 21:09:05.680  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5fbd0686] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.245  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.292  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.292  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.303  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.2;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Users\iko\Desktop\TensorFlow\bazel;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\iko\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\iko\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\iko\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\iko\Desktop\TensorFlow\bazel;C:\Users\iko\Desktop\TensorFlow\bazel.exe;;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.487  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.487 DEBUG 7080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.487  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2450 ms
    Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.682  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.686  WARN 7080 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
    2019-02-10 21:09:06.883  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    2019-02-10 21:09:08.537 ERROR 7080 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : null
    2019-02-10 21:09:08.547  WARN 7080 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    2019-02-10 21:09:08.549  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2019-02-10 21:09:08.562  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    2019-02-10 21:09:08.565  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2019-02-10 21:09:08.578  INFO 7080 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2019-02-10 21:09:08.593 ERROR 7080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed



        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at com.savetweet.tweet.TweetApplication.main(TweetApplication.java:35) [classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
        Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: null
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:135) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
        ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Show backtrace.

Comment: Unable to open JDBC connection is nothing at all to do with your mapping, and everything to do with your definition of persistence unit. But you haven't specified that ...

Comment: I added console output and application.properties file.